# Is Latent Semantic Indexing (LSI) a Statistical Classification algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, semantic-web, information-retrieval, classification

Is Latent Semantic Indexing (LSI) a Statistical Classification algorithm? Why or why not?

Basically, I'm trying to figure out why [the Wikipedia page for Statistical Classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) does not mention LSI. I'm just getting into this stuff and I'm trying to see how all the different approaches for classifying something relate to one another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they're not quite the same. Statistical classification is intended to separate items into categories as cleanly as possible -- to make a clean decision about whether item X is more like the items in group A or group B, for example.

LSI is intended to show the degree to which items are similar or different and, primarily, find items that show a degree of similarity to an specified item. While this is *similar*, it's not quite the same.

Answer (score 3):

LSI/LSA is eventually a technique for **dimensionality reduction**, and usually is coupled with a nearest neighbor algorithm to make it a into classification system. Hence in itself, its only a way of "indexing" the data in lower dimension using SVD.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read about [LSI on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing) ?  It says it uses matrix factorization ([SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)), which in turn is sometimes used in classification.

Answer (score 1):

The primary distinction in machine learning is between "supervised" and "unsupervised" modeling.

Usually the words "statistical classification" refer to supervised models, but not always.

With supervised methods the training set contains a "ground-truth" label that you build a model to predict. When you evaluate the model, the goal is to predict the best guess at (or probability distribution of) the true label, which you will not have at time of evaluation.  Often there's a performance metric and it's quite clear what the right vs wrong answer is.

Unsupervised classification methods attempt to cluster a large number of data points which may appear to vary in complicated ways into a smaller number of "similar" categories.  Data in each category ought to be similar in some kind of 'interesting' or 'deep' way.  Since there is no "ground truth" you can't evaluate 'right or wrong', but 'more' vs 'less' interesting or useful.

Similarly evaluation time you can place new examples into potentially one of the clusters (crisp classification) or give some kind of weighting quantifying how similar or different looks like the "archetype" of the cluster.

So in some ways supervised and unsupervised models can yield something which is a "prediction", prediction of class/cluster label, but they are intrinsically different.

Often the goal of an unsupervised model is to provide more intelligent and powerfully compact inputs for a subsequent supervised model.